# Gradle Build Failed with build tool 3.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

I using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0` and gradle build failed with error below.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.0.2) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

[image]

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your support library version to `com.android.support:support-v4-27.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different
>   version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.0.2) classpath. You
>   should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

**FYI**

***You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution***.

- Use **`com.android.support`** same version. You can use **`27.1.1`**.

**DEMO**

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:design:27.1.1"
```

And upgrade below version from ***Module Level*** `build.gradle`.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

**Note**

You can Upgrade your  **`gradle`** version.

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2
```

Comment: do you mean all `build.gradle` ? I cant even find the error mention `26.1.0`

Comment: all `build.gradle` upgrade to `compileSdkVersion 27` and `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"` ?

Comment: @ImHappy Only Module Level

Comment: module level do you mean `android/app/build.gradle` ?

Comment: @ImHappy Yes yes

Comment: @ImHappy Kindly `Clean-Rebuild-Restart` IDE . And show your `build.gradle` module level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169933/discussion-between-im-happy-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happened because you have multiple conflicted dependencies of `'com.android.support:support-v4'`. So, you need to use only one version of `support-v4` by excluding all other support-v4 library inside of your dependencies.

You first need to check the dependencies tree by running the following command in your terminal inside your root project directory:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

or use the following command if you're using Windows:

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

`app` is your module name.

You will get the dependencies tree then. After that, check all libraries that using the support library. **Exclude** the support-v4 library from them. For example, if you have a dependency with support library something like this:

```
implementation 'com.package.libraryname:1.0.0'
```

then you need to exclude the support-v4 with this:

```
implementation ('com.package.libraryname:1.0.0') {    
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Add the same `exclude` line to all conflicted support-v4 library.

Comment: I thought gradle 3.0 doesn't support the exclude config